# how to get start with C, C++ coding in unix, and what is the basic packeges needed to install at first?

Tags: 18.04, c, compiler

I am a beginner to use linux os. 
What is the basic packges needed to install to compile a C,C++ code in terminal box ?
and, please give the command to install it .

:(

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu?